# Jekyll - Include file to point to its own md file

Tags: include, jekyll

If I include a file like so:

```
{% include_relative _layouts/tile.html %}
```

within my index.html file, how can I get tile.html to use the front matter of tile.md rather than index.md?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be better to have the **title** in the config or a *data* file.

But in this case, if you want to access the frontmatter of any post/page you can do it by specifying the path where it is located as:

```
{%assign title_post = site.posts | where:"path","_posts/title.md" |first%}

{{title_post.title}}
```

Or if it is a page (as it seems to be) use `site.pages` instead of `site.posts`.